# show unit test success/failure count in sonarqube

Tags: unit-testing, sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I'm using an asp.net MVC project with VSTS and Sonar (5.6.3). 
My unit test coverage is showing up on my Sonar Dashboard.

However, I didn't find a way to display number of unit test passed/failed on the dashboard.

Any help?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You won't find any way to display those measures on the pre-configured project home page. However, if you have fed Unit Test Execution data, they will be available on the [Measures](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/component_measures?id=org.sonarsource.sonarqube%3Asonarqube), page, and on the [Coverage](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/component_measures/domain/Coverage?id=org.sonarsource.sonarqube%3Asonarqube) sub-page.

To be explicit, this data cannot be "intuited" from your test coverage reports, but must be provided separately.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I could see the number of unit tests on the home page (coverage section) of yours. It doesn't show up for me. Do I need to setup something? My configuration - SonarQube, VSTS, .NET

Comment: You have to feed Unit Test Execution reports @Rabi

Comment: thanks for the reply.back with a question.Do you have any example of feeding the data to Sonar?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure my issue is relate to yours. I am using karma-sonarqube-unit-reporter to generate output.xml for sonar. The reason number of unit tests doesnt show on home page is in the output.xml all the file paths are not defined. Change all the file paths to test files paths solve the problem. Hope this helps.